# SWIFT 2 - UICollectionView - slow scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, swift2

I have setup a uicollectionview in my project that get data from a JSON file. Everything works good however, the scrolling is very slow and when the view is scrolling the coming cell, for few moments shows the content of the cell before.

I have tried using `dispatch_async` but it still very slow and jumpy.

any Idea what am I doing wrong?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let videoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("VideoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        let communityViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("community_id")

        videoCell.frame.size.width = (communityViewController?.view.frame.size.width)!
        videoCell.center.x = (communityViewController?.view.center.x)!

        videoCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        videoCell.layer.borderWidth = 2


        let fileURL = NSURL(string:self.UserVideosInfo[indexPath.row][2])
        let asset = AVAsset(URL: fileURL!)
        let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            //self.showIndicator()

            let NameLabelString = self.UserVideosInfo[indexPath.row][0]
            let CommentLabelString = self.UserVideosInfo[indexPath.row][1]
            let DateLabelString = self.UserVideosInfo[indexPath.row][3]

            let buttonPlayUserVideo = videoCell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
            let nameLabel = videoCell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
            let commentUserVideo = videoCell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
            let dateUserVideo = videoCell.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
            let thumbUserVideo = videoCell.viewWithTag(5) as! UIImageView
            let deleteUserVideo = videoCell.viewWithTag(6) as! UIButton

            buttonPlayUserVideo.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "indexPlayBtn")
            deleteUserVideo.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "indexDeleteBtn")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {



                nameLabel.text = NameLabelString
                commentUserVideo.text = CommentLabelString
                dateUserVideo.text = DateLabelString

                self.shadowText(nameLabel)
                self.shadowText(commentUserVideo)
                self.shadowText(dateUserVideo)

                if let cgImage = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil) {
                    thumbUserVideo.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
                }


            }

        }

        //THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
        videoCell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        videoCell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale


        return videoCell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first** - you are working with UI objects from global queue and seems like without any purpose. That is forbidden - or behavior will be undefined.

**Secondary**, the mostly heavy operation is creation of thumbnail which you perform on main queue.
Consider using of the `AVAssetImageGenerator`'s method

```
public func generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes(requestedTimes: [NSValue], completionHandler handler: AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler)
```

instead of your own asyncs.

**At third**, `viewWithTag` is pretty heavy operation causing enumeration on `subviews`. Consider to declare properties in the cell for views which you need.

UPD: to declare properties in a cell, create subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` with appropriate properties as IBOutlets. Then, in your view controller `viewDidLoad` implementation, call

```
collecionView.registerClass(<YourCellSubclass>.dynamicType,  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"VideoCell")
```

Or, if your collection view cell is configured in the Storyboard, specify the class of the cell and connect its subviews to class' outlets directly in the cell's settings window in Interface Builder.

**At fourth**, your cells are being reused by a collection view. Each time your cell is going out of visible area, it is removed from collection view and is put to reuse queue. When you scroll back to the cell, your view controller is asked again to provide a cell. And you're fetching the thumbnail for the video again for each newly appeared cell. Consider caching of already fetched thumbnails by storing them in some array by collectionView's `indexPath.item` index.

Comment: thank you, I have tried. But How can I declare properties in the cell for views instead of using viewWithTag ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Don't forget to increase answer's stat and mark it correct if it helps to you :)

Comment: Every time i try to connect to IBOutlets I get the error:     Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: The nameUsrVideo outlet from the VideoCollectionView to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: It's because your outlet is declared not in the cell's class but in the view controller's class. Did you read what I've written about configuring cell subclass?

Comment: thank you, done all the changes and I can see that the scrolling is slow because of the images generated. I was looking how to save the cache, any good tutorial?

Comment: Basically I believe you can do it even without tutorial. Create a map in your view controller [NSString, UIImage], and store there images you generated by your video file name/URL. If there is image in the map already, get it from the map instead of generation. If you want also persist thumbnail images, you can store them somewhere in a cache with a name related to your video file name/URL. Then load cached images appropriately to your map in viewDidLoad. Good luck!